# What is ServiceObjectiveId?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure

I am trying to get a hang of using [Windows Azure Sql Database Managment Libraries](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/managing-windows-azure-sql-databases-using-the-management-libraries-for-net)

but the examples omit how to create a database. I am having issues on the final part since I do not know what a `ServiceObjectiveId` is.

```
DatabaseCreateParameters dbParams = new DatabaseCreateParameters();
//default sql azure collation is SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS
dbParams.CollationName = "SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS";
dbParams.Edition = "Web";
dbParams.MaximumDatabaseSizeInGB = 1;
dbParams.Name = Name;
dbParams.ServiceObjectiveId = "?????"

client.Databases.Create(Cache.ProgramSettings.DefaultServerConnection.ServerName
            , dbParams);
```

I've spent about 2 hours trying to find info on the net about what this means and how to get it but can not find it for my life.

## EDIT

In reference to Shiva's answer I omitted the `ServiceObjectiveId` and am now getting an error stating that a uri resource could not be found. If I dig deeper into the error I can find my request which seems to look fine.

```
<ServiceResource xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
<Name>SQL Azure</Name>
<Edition>Web</Edition>
<MaxSizeGB>1</MaxSizeGB>
<CollationName>SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS</CollationName>
</ServiceResource>
```

## Edit 2

I checked the request uri and that seems to look completely fine as well.

```
{https://management.core.windows.net//obscured#/services/sqlservers/servers/obscured#.database.windows.net/databases}
```

Comment: I am trying to automate a process, otherwise I would definitely use the portal.

Comment: It looks like some kind of unique identifier, what values does it have for a database created in the Azure Portal? It could potentially just by default by a guid per database encoded as a string.

Answer (score 0):

[From the Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn505701.aspx), the `Create` request doesn't require the `ServiceObjectiveId` parameter and appears to be a `GUID` that is assigned and returned to you in the Response payload.

#### Create Database - Request Body

> The format of the request body is as follows:

```
<ServiceResource xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
  <Name>testdb</Name>
  <Edition>Web</Edition>
  <MaxSizeBytes>1048576</MaxSizeBytes>
  <CollationName>SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS</CollationName> <!-- Optional -->
</ServiceResource>
```

So can you try it without assigning anything to that `ServiceObjectiveId` parameter?

Comment: I tried it without the `ServiceObjectiveID` and got an error `ResourceNotFound: The Uri doesn't match any specific service operation.` I assumed it was because I had an invalid `ServiceObjectiveId`

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't the error message mean that the end point wasn't found?

Comment: Im not sure. I wouldn't understand why that would happen in this scenario. My server string is hardcoded and it works when I use it to run queries in the same app. I dug deeper into the exception and found my request. I updated my answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

The ServiceObjectiveId is a component of an Azure service identifier that is used to return service levels.

The following link provides some reference information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn505709.aspx

Notice the serviceObjectiveId  parameter used in the request url:
https://management.core.windows.net:8443/{subscriptionId}/services/sqlservers/servers/{serverName}/serviceobjectives/{**serviceObjectiveId**}

Answer (score 0):

It is `pricing tier`. You can get a list of the available objectives for a server using:

```
var credentials =  GetAzureCredentials();
var client = new SqlManagementClient(creds);
var objectives = await client.ServiceObjectives.ListAsync("ServerName");
var objective = objectives.Single(x => x.Name == "S1");

//  ServiceObjectiveId = objective.Id
```